# Is it possible to draw a polygonal patch in a polar plot in matplotlib?

Tags: matplotlib

I have the vertices of a polygon represented in polar coordinates (r,theta). And I would like to draw a filled polygon specifically in a polar plot.

I am aware that add_patch can be used to draw in the xy mode of matplotlib. Is there an equivalent for the polar plotting mode?

Comment: What have you tried?  I suspect you will need to dig into the transforms a bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use ax.add_line() on a polar subplot:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

r = np.ones(100)
theta = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,100)
polygon = matplotlib.patches.Polygon(zip(theta,r),fill=False)

fig = plt.figure()
polar = fig.add_subplot(111,projection='polar')
polar.add_line(polygon)
polar.autoscale()

plt.show()
```

Another way is to use ax.fill() with the points of your polygon.

Instead of:

```
polar.add_line()
```

you could use:

```
polar.fill(theta,r,fill=False)
```

And you will get the same result without:

```
polygon = matplotlib.patches.Polygon(zip(theta,r),fill=False)
```

[image]